# Does meta tag "charset=utf-8" ensure the correct visualization in any browser?

Tags: html, browser, utf-8, character-encoding, multilingual

I am working on a website with multilingual characters (Latin,Cyrillic,Japanese, Chinese and so on) mixed together. 
 
I've used the following meta-tag to ensure the correct visualization of the content:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

My question is: is this sufficient to be 100% sure that all the users will visualize the content without any problem? Do their OS need to have specific support for such characters?

Silly example: do all the modern browsers and/or OS support the Korean Alphabet/characters or are the users required to install them?

Comment: You need to use a `font` that is unicode and that supports all the languages you want. And it should be one that is *web-safe*. All browsers support all characters but you need to use a font that contains them..

Comment: I'm using the `font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`. Is this the case?

Comment: Not sure about Helvetica, but at least Arial does support most languages.

Comment: See http://typophile.com/node/101505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `meta` tag does not guarantee anything. It declares that the encoding is UTF-8. It may be overridden by HTTP headers. See [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php) by the W3C.

If the encoding has been declared as UTF-8, and it it actually *is* UTF-8, then you can be pretty safe that are all browsers get the characters right. Whether they *display* them depends partly on availability of fonts, partly on `font-family` settings in CSS; see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html). It does not depend on the OS.

Regarding Korean (Hangul) characters, the [Fileformat.info data on font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d55c/fontsupport.htm) seems to be too limited (I have reported this to the author). In addition to fonts listed there, at least the following fonts contain them, or at least a large part of them: Batang, BatangChe, Dotum, DotumChe, Gulim, GulimChe, Gungsuh, GugsuhChe, Malgun Gothic, Sun-ExtA.

So you could write a long list of fonts (in order of preference) containing Korean characters, as the `font-family` value. I would expect this to work in most modern computers, but not all. To maximize the odds, you would need to use a downloadable font (web font) via `@font-face`, such as Sun-ExtA, which appears to be a free font, available from Alan Wood’s [repository](http://www.alanwood.net/downloads/index.html). Beware that it is a large font, and you would need it in a few formats, generated e.g. with [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com), to cover different browsers. Like most large fonts, it has one (regular) typeface only, so you should not try to use it as bold or italic; make sure you override and bold and italic settings that browsers tend to have for many HTML elements, like heading elements.